# Deterministic malloc in a forked process

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

What I want is to have the forked process, which is copy of its parent process, to get the same addresses returned from each malloc function call, as its parent process. How can I achieve this?

Actually what I am trying to achieve is to have two replicated processes, which execute the same thing. I am basically doing this to detect soft errors, that is, if there is any divergence, it must be due to an error, not non-determinism. Now, since malloc is non-deterministic, it will make the two processes diverge, which I want to avoid.

If that is not possible, can I log addresses returned by malloc for the parent process and use the same addresses for the forked process. Would this work?

Comment: This is a strange request; would you mind sharing which design requires this?

Comment: Are you trying to build shared memory on your own?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to implement redundant execution to detect soft errors, that is, If there is any divergence, it should be due to an error, not due to non-determinism.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of for getting different addresses is ASLR. Turn it off at the kernel level and you'll probably get the same addresses. But relying on this seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: Now that I see what you're doing, I think it's still misguided for *most purposes*. Two forked copies of a process will, in general, already diverge for other reasons such as having different pids, different orders of success acquiring exclusive resources (which may in turn lead to different `malloc` patterns), etc. If your program is (almost) purely computational, these differences may not matter, but it still seems extremely fragile.

Comment: R. If I just log the addresses returned by malloc in the original process and let the forked process read from the log at each malloc call, would it still not work? Assume that we are working with a single threaded process, so no ordering problem is there.

Comment: I completely agree with @R.. There are other things that enter that make this fragile, descheduling and signals e.g for IO. At some point your application will write results somewhere, in one execution an IO request might be effective immediately in the other the process might be descheduled, some system functions may temporarily allocate different buffers according to that etc. The only states that should be relevant for your purpose are your own application variables. For everything else you can't expect any guarantees.

Comment: @Jens, Ya I know. That is why, at this moment I was using my own memory managment method, which is deterministic, but its just a simple one which just keeps on allocating memory and there is no corresponding free. But I was actually worried about memory allocation going on under the hood, for example when using library functions, such as printf, that internally uses malloc. I have no way to handle non-determinism due to those.

Comment: @MetallicPriest, You can always write your own malloc.  Getting it linked into printf() would be a big challenge, but could be possible using the right linker directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is simply no way to do this with `malloc`.  The returned address of `malloc` is not defined to be deterministic in any way (especially a portable one).  To attempt to sync it up between process`s, even a child and parent one, is likely a fruitless effort.

Can you give us some more details on why you want to do this?  Perhaps there is another way to achieve the effect you're looking for.

Comment: I am trying to implement redundant execution, so that I can detect soft errors, that is, if there is any divergence, it should be due to an error, not due to non-determinism. So, I want the two processes, that is the parent and its replica (the forked one) to execute in exactly the same way in the absence of errors.

Answer (score 3):

If your system is Linux, then you'll get more reproducible addresses by disabling the address space randomization. You can achieve that with this command (to be run as root)

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

(but address space randomization is a feature which may improve your system security)

However, this don't guarantee that parent and child process will get the same behavior (because there is a small difference between them: the return of `fork()` and their pid). And you cannot be sure that their allocation pattern is similar enough. Imagine if after the fork the (forked) program executes something like

```
 char *p = malloc (8192*(3 + (getpid() % 10) + time(NULL) % 100));
```

then you should expect the malloc to request widely different sizes in parent and in child, with a different malloc returned address. So this contrieved example shows that your requirement is not realistic.

Comment: I don't see how disabling ASR would make this ever work. ASR impacts the virtual address space layout (as you obviously know), which is inherited after a fork(). Malloc() in each child simply allocates spaces on the heap in this layout, and so should always diverge or at least could do so. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @gnometorule: The virtual address layout is relevant to `malloc` because `malloc` uses virtual memory. Each memory block (in a Unix) is either from the process (the `brk` space) or from a `mmap` block. `mmap` is directly affected by ASLR.

Comment: Sure. But how does this apply to the question at hand?

Comment: @gnometorule: For large allocations, the `malloc()` in `glibc` uses `mmap()` to acquire a new block of memory, rather than allocating space in the current heap.  If ASLR is enabled, this new anonymous mapping is given a randomised address by the kernel, which is reflected in the address returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the standard `malloc`. But you can write your own custom allocator that has a deterministic way to allocate. E.g. as the allocation pool, use a sufficiently sized `static char pool[POOL_SIZE];` The address of `pool` remains invariant across a `fork()`. All pointers into `pool` as well. Voilà!

Answer (score -2):

You probably want to use [shared memory](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html). You can't make malloc return the same value since once the first call executes, that memory has been allocated and can't be given to another process.

Comment: How so? Different processes have entirely independent address spaces for their own, separate virtual memory...

Comment: Well, the address spaces are different, but the dynamically obtained mallod pointers could have the same numerical value (but pointing inside different spaces).

Comment: @KerrekSB Very true in a literal sense. I was interpreting the OPs question as wanting to point to the same block of physical memory, which is obviously incorrect.